# Uniform convergence proof

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

How can I show that the function $ f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+nx} $ converges uniformly on the interval $ x \in [1, \infty ) $ 
I have already proven the pointwise limit to be $ f(x)=1  $

I am working with the definition 
$ \forall  \epsilon \gt0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N}  $ such that $ \forall x \in [1, \infty)  $ and $ \forall n \ge  N \mid \frac{nx}{1+nx} - 1 \mid \lt \epsilon $

Do I need to produce a value of N or a value of $ \epsilon $?

Comment: The whole point of uniform convergence is that no matter what $x$ is, when you fix an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, $N$ should depends only on $\epsilon$. Working with the definition you already wrote out, can you work out why $N$ is such in this case?

Comment: Your first sentence is a question about uniform continuity of a function.  Your definition is of uniform convergence of a sequence of functions.  Can you clarify?

Comment: You need to clarify the question.

Comment: [Showing Uniform Convergence of $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+nx}$ for $x \geq 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588198/showing-uniform-convergence-of-f-nx-fracnx1nx-for-x-geq-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are seeking after a proof that the function $f: x \mapsto 1$ on $[1, \infty[$ is the uniform limit of the sequence $(f_{n})$ because of your title and you saying that you have worked out that $f$ is the pointwise limit.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. If $N \geq 1,$ then $f_{n} \to f$ uniformly on $[1, \infty[$ iff
$$\bigg| \frac{nx}{1+nx} - 1 \bigg| = \frac{1}{1+nx} \leq \frac{1}{1+N}  < \varepsilon,$$
which means that
$$N > \frac{1}{\varepsilon} - 1.$$
So taking $N := \lceil \frac{1}{\varepsilon} - 1 \rceil + 1$ suffices.

Answer (score 0):

We have $f_n'(x) = {n \over (nx+1)^2}$, hence $|f_n'(x)| \le 1$ for all $x \ge 1$. Then
the mean value theorem shows that $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \le |x-y|$ from which
uniform continuity follows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show uniform convergence of the sequence of function $f_n$, Use *[M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test)*. That is $M_n=\sup\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|:x\in[1,\infty)\} $,where $f$ is the pointwise limit.
Now $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on the given domain iff $M_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. 
Here $M_n=\frac{1}{n+1}(\rightarrow0)$.